# Print out the numbers from the for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, substring

The Return type is void

No input parameters

Print out the numbers calculated results separated by a space using current number add the next number from 0 to (a+b).

An example would be if the numbers for the for loop are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 then it would add 0+1, 1+2, 2+3, 3+4, 4+5, 5+6 and print out those values just like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.

I honestly have no clue how to do this so I'm not going to lie about it so can someone help me code it and explain or just help me with it.

```
public class ForFogMe
{
   public int a, b;
   public String str;

    public void addUp(){  
       
     for(a = 0; a <= 6; a ++){
         System.out.print(a);        
        }
       
       String s = Integer.toString(a);
       System.out.println();
       System.out.print(s.substring(0,2) );
       
    }
   
   public static void main(String args[]){
        
       ForFogMe me = new ForFogMe();
       me.addUp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
public static void addUp(){
    final int[] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int[] result = new int[array.length-1];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        result[i]=array[i]+array[i+1];
    }
    result[3]=array[array.length-1];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(result[i]+" ");
    }
    

      
   }
```

Test case (array):

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Outputs:

```
1 3 5 6 9 11
```

Note: The array size does not matter.

Comment: Sorry I might have said it wrong but there needs to be a 6 I meant to say it like the max it six so the numbers would be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: yes it does but if the test case is  0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and you have to do 0+1, 1+2, 2+3, 3+4, 4+5, 5+6 that means the output should be 1,3,5,7,9,11 not 1,5,9,6

Comment: this works perfectly but how would I do it without the final int[] array being a parameter?

Comment: @Vobacocm I've done it for you. Does that help? If it does, please consider upvoting!

Comment: @Vobacocm Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to print sum of the numbers from 0 to 6 you would do it simply like this:

```
public void addUp() {
   for(a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
       System.out.print(a+(a+1) + ",");
   }
   System.out.print("\b"); // to delete last comma
}
```

In first iteration `a` is `0` `a+1` is `1` so you print their sum like `(a+(a+1) + ",")` which outputs `"1,"`. It repeats until it reaches `6`. At the end we have `1,3,5,7,9,11,` so I used `System.out.print("\b");` to delete last char, so we get `1,3,5,7,9,11`